# What is the difference between EventEmitter vs EventEmitter<T> in Angular 2?

Tags: generics, typescript, angular

What is the difference between `EventEmitter` vs `EventEmitter<T>` in Angular2? What are the benefits of using `EventEmitter<T>`? Is `EventEmitter` same as `EventEmitter<any>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `EventEmitter<T>`, you get the power to pass any type variable as the argument, while safely being able to define the return of the Emitter as `<T>` aka the same type. I believe this is called a [Generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).